# VisualStateManager.GoToState() ignores useTransitions

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have a UserControl that has visual states in it. When the control constructs, I want to move to one of the states which is the "initial" one (not Default - there are modifications).

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += MyUserControl_Loaded;
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "HideImageState", false);
}
```

However, when the control loads up, there's an obvious transition happening (the one that HideImageState represents).

Why is that if I am passing in useTransitions?

Comment: What's the storyboard in HideImageState and transitions to HideImageState?

Comment: I hate to be blunt here, but `GoToState()` does not ignore transitions. You had better include your `StoryBoard` XAML so we can see what the real problem is.

Comment: It is polite to mark the correct/best answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't providing any more information, there are few things to work through "generally" that might help. Again, I am shooting from the hip with common problems...

The first is that your storyboard is inaccurate. If you created your transitions in Blend, then this is not likely. But if you coded them by hand, then the targets may not be what you expect.

The animations could also be occurring but being occluded by other elements in the UI. This can sometimes occur when you are resizing an object inside a container that cannot stretch.

Finally, and most importantly, if your visual state transitions are in a user control that is wrapped in a `Viewbox` then your view states are ignored for some reason.

There are other possible reasons for you to get the result you are seeing. However, with so little information given, I can't keep on guessing. I would assume one of the above three reasons.

Best of luck!